# Ruby error on non-ruby site

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ruby-on-rails

A friends of mine have a shared hosting with many sites hosted. There is ruby on rails, php, xslt/xml sites using mysql or postgress. Today one of the xslt sites displays this error:

```
Passenger error #2
An error occurred while trying to access '..../config/environment.rb': Cannot stat '..../config/environment.rb': Permission denied (13)
Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the relevant file permissions.
```

This is, as I Know, a ruby error (*.rb), but there is no ruby app here! And no any config/ catalogue.
The error log says:

```
(13)Permission denied: /home/..../.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

The .htaccess file in the htdocs directory is present and have 777 permission for now.
I haven't any idea what does it mean.

Answer (score 1):

Set 'PassengerEnabled off'.

Comment: You would do this in the vhost config for the site that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error message from mod_ruby (Phusion Passenger) in your apache install.  mod_ruby runs as the owner of /your/ruby/app/config/environment.rb by default.

can you post your httpd.conf, or at least the mod_ruby bits?